# Kohana - Incorrect table name - issue

Tags: kohana

I'm running Kohana stable release 3.2.0, just downloaded.
My database configuration is done and bootstrap contains orm and database modules enabled. So is my model created.

My request looks like this:

```
$user = ORM::factory('user',$post)->find();
if($user->count_all()){
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($user);
 echo '</pre>';
}
```

Basically it should return some data, but it gives me an error.

> Database_Exception [ 1103 ]: Incorrect table name '' [ SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` FROM `` ]

Is this normal, that it displays empty table?

1. If I update configuration with table prefix, it displays prefix, but does not show table.
2. If I update model with protected variable `$table_name='user';` it still does not see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user = ORM::factory('user',$post)->find();
if($user->loaded()){
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($user);
 echo '</pre>';
}
```

Use [`loaded()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/using#check-that-orm-loaded-a-record) method to check that user was successfully loaded from DB.

Comment: ok, right, i was debugin'it. But the question still not understandable.

Comment: does `$user->find()` call work? If so, your table settings are correct.

Comment: Yeah. They are ok. It seems that, if i recreate tables in database it starts working, with no code editing. Now I'm curious why and what was the problem.